# Could analog computers be used to solve a set of PDEs w/o the traditional numerical instability problems that come from discretizing the domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computer-science, computability, computational-mathematics

The question is simple.  Could analog computers (for example, electrical analog computers) in effect avoid traditional numerical instability problems that come from solving a set of PDEs over a discretized domain? Progress on significant physical problems (the computational aspects at least) are often substantially delayed because of time spent figuring out how to avoiding numerical instabilities, and often the solution ultimately utilized is just to hit the problem with lots of artificial diffusion, which seems unrigorous at best.

Also, since many physical theories are often significant approximations themselves, maybe some accuracy could be sacrificed (in moving to analog computers) for the greater benefit of avoiding numerical instabilities.

Comment: Yes but the trade off is other numerical issues resulting from the nature of analog computers instead of discretization: the accuracy of the analog solution depends on the precision and standardization of the manufactured components like op amps, or gears in mechanical computers etc. These tend to wear over time and use, being physical/electrical. Second, I am pretty sure one has to carefully transform problems into the appropriate range/units/scale so that the solutions can be meaningfully computed with the devices.

Comment: The analog model would have to be an accurate model of the system being modeled; that is nit necessarily a simple proposition Mostly likely, an analog model would itself have some 'discretisation' of sorts.

Comment: Analog computers are basically lumped parameter systems. To handle PDEs requires another kind of machines...

Comment: @Cesareo differential analyzers can easily handle complicated *ODE systems*, and this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4051222 suggests approximately solving PDEs by applying finite differences to one or more partials and then using a DA to solve the resulting ODE. What other machines did you have in mind?

Comment: I also used analog computers. The proposed system is still a system with concentrated parameters, terribly difficult to calibrate. I propose the digital solution.